# Conditional Sum of 2D Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4 (but in reality an arbitrary amount of) 2D arrays like so:

```
import numpy as np

c1 = np.ones((75, 100))
c2 = np.ones((75, 100))
c3 = np.ones((75, 100))
c4 = np.ones((75, 100))

c1[22:42, 5:35] = np.random.rand(20, 30) / 2
c2[25:45, 25:55] = np.random.rand(20, 30) / 2
c3[28:48, 45:75] = np.random.rand(20, 30) / 2
c4[31:51, 65:95] = np.random.rand(20, 30) / 2
```

What I'd like to do is sum the arrays everywhere except for where the arrays overlap. And where there is an overlap, the value ought to be the left array. My instinct is to use `np.where`, but I cannot think of a clever/neat way of doing so.

Hopefully the below image makes this clear

```
c_arrays = np.array([c1, c2, c3, c4])
result = c_arrays.sum(axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(result)
```

[image]

---

**Edit**: I came up with an awful, recursive solution that at least shows the result I'm looking for. My hope is that someone can offer a much cleaner approach, in particular that isn't recursive

```
c_arrays_1 = []
for ci, cj in zip(c_arrays, c_arrays[1:]):
    c = np.where(ci + cj < 1, ci, ci + cj - 1)
    c_arrays_1.append(c)

c_arrays_2 = []
for ci, cj in zip(c_arrays_1, c_arrays_1[1:]):
    c = np.where(ci + cj < 1, ci, ci + cj - 1)
    c_arrays_2.append(c)

c_arrays_3 = []
for ci, cj in zip(c_arrays_2, c_arrays_2[1:]):
    c = np.where(ci + cj < 1, ci, ci + cj - 1)
    c_arrays_3.append(c)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(c_arrays_3[0])
```

[image]

Comment: How/where are the overlaps defined?

Comment: `np.where(c1 != 1, c1, c1 + c2)`? For example? Are you looking to generalise something like this?

Comment: So you array is initialized at 1, and some parts are random numbers, which could also evaluate to 1. How to distinguish the two?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think that's the idea. @Divakar the overlaps are not defined explicitly, but could be found with something like `np.where(result < 3, 1, 0)`. Better yet, `result < n-1` where `n` is the number of arrays.

Comment: I think a mcve would be nice - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Divakar Maybe I'm too wrapped up in my own use case, but I fail to see how this isn't M, C, or V? My example is missing the desired solution because I can't figure out how to obtain it... So I'm giving the best possible explanation I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive method that I think fits your requirements:

```
def condsum(*arrs, r = 1):
    if len(arrs) == 1:
        return arrs[0]
    else:
        a = condsum(*arrs[1:], r = r)
        return np.where(a == r, arrs[0], a)
```

Then you'd just need to do

```
plt.imshow(condsum(c1, c2, c3, c4))
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for ignoring my request for a solution without recursion :) Clearly did not know what was best for me.